# Send data to IoT device on home network from remote server

Tags: networking, web, m2m

To stop an internet connected device (lets say it's an internet connected thermostat) from having to poll the remote server all the time to see if the user has changed its settings how would a server send data to that device when needed? I understand how to initiate a connection from the internet connected device, just not the other way round.

It's safe to assume that the device would have already registered it's details with the server in some kind of set up process initiated by the device.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SignalR, in these links:

1. http://signalr.net/
2. http://www.asp.net/signalr
3. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/590660/Introduction-to-SignalR

HTH